# Few problems at the same time, PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, conflict, ob-start

I'm working on one website but i'm confused.

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
session_start();
define('FORUM_ROOT', 'forum/');
require FORUM_ROOT.'include/common.php';
// Where will we go after login?
$forum_page['redirect_url'] = 'http://l2topsites.net/';
$forum_page['form_action'] = forum_link($forum_url['login']);
$forum_page['hidden_fields'] = array(
    'form_sent'     => '<input type="hidden" name="form_sent" value="1" />',
    'redirect_url'  => '<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="'.forum_htmlencode($forum_page['redirect_url']).'" />',
    'csrf_token'    => '<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="'.generate_form_token($forum_page['form_action']).'" />'
);
include "conf.php";
$opala = $_GET['p'];
if (isset($opala)) {
    $page = '_data/'.$opala.'.php';
} else {
    $page = "_data/indexa.php";
}
if (!is_file($page)) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:history.back();">This page not found!</a>';
} else {
    include "_data/".basename($page) ;
}
$sredata = ob_get_clean();
if(!isset($title)) $title = "[L2TopSites] - Top Lineage 2 Ranking Sites";
$online = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(user_id) FROM `foo_online`"));
$online = $online['COUNT(user_id)'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title><? echo $title; ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="bg" />
        <base href="http://l2topsites.net" />
        <meta name="robots" content="all,follow" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="0G89ZsSF30caf4PJk17uLLtejlwnl8oO2mUN4ywZCw8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Top Lineage2 Server only on TopZone.eu" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="topzone, lineage2, servers, rank, votes, top10, top25, top100, lineage2 servers" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=3600" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/min/f=style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="maintop"></div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="lpanel">
                        <?
                        if (!$forum_user['is_guest'])
                        {
                            echo "<div class=\"usermenu\">";
                            echo "<a href=\"myhome\"><img src=\"images/button1.png\" width=\"90\" height=\"23\" alt=\"\" /></a><br />";
                            echo "<a href=\"forum/pun_pm/inbox/\"><img src=\"images/button2.png\" width=\"90\" height=\"23\" alt=\"\" /></a><br />";
                            echo "<a href=\"forum/logout/".$forum_user['id']."/".$forum_user['csrf_token']."/\"><img src=\"images/button3.png\" width=\"90\" height=\"23\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
                            echo "</div><div id=\"ltext\" style=\"padding-top: 5px;\">";
                            echo "Logged in as: <a href=\"forum/user/".$forum_user['id']."\">".$forum_user['username']."</a>";
                            if($forum_user['is_admmod']==1){
                                echo " | <a href=\"admin\">Admin Panel</a>";
                            }
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            ?>
                        <form action="<?php echo $forum_page['form_action'] ?>" method="post">
                            <?php echo implode("\n\t\t", $forum_page['hidden_fields'])."\n" ?>
                            <table border="0">
                                <tr><td width="10"><img class="img" src="images/user.png" width="17" height="19" alt="" /></td><td><input type="text" name="req_username" id="userinput" /></td></tr>
                                <tr><td width="10"><img class="img" src="images/pass.png" width="17" height="19" alt="" /></td><td><input type="password" name="req_password" id="passinput" /></td></tr>
                            </table>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="login" />
                            <a href="forum/register/" id="register"><img src="images/register.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                            <div id="ltext">
                                <a href="forum/request/password/">Forget Password?</a>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="input" name="save_pass" value="1" /><span>Remember me</span></div>
                        </form>
                        <? } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mbaner1">
                    <div id="mb1l"></div>
                    <div id="mb1b">
                        <div id="mb1">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/baner1.png" width="728" height="90" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mb2r"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="left">
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div class="mback">
                        <div id="box1t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/news">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div class="mback">
                        <div id="box2t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/list">All Servers (by Vote)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/servers">All Servers (by Date)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/plist">Premium Servers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/searchserver">Search Server</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/add">Add Server</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div class="mback">
                        <div id="box3t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/crests">Crests</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/forum/forum/2/">L2 Guides</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/forum">Forum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div id="aback">
                        <div id="box4t"></div>
                        <div id="adsense"><script type="text/javascript">
                            <!--
google_ad_client="pub-4584526598914996";google_ad_slot="3047263056";google_ad_width=121;google_ad_height=240;//-->
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript"
                                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                        </script></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="mcontent">
                    <div id="glineage"></div>
                    <div id="mcontenttop"></div>
                    <div id="mcontentt">
                        <?php
                        echo $sredata;
                        $btemi = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM foo_topics"));
                        $broitemi = $btemi['COUNT(id)'];
                        $bposts = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM foo_posts"));
                        $broipostove = $bposts['COUNT(id)'];
                        $bservers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM s_servers WHERE `odobren` = '1'"));
                        $broiserveri = $bservers['COUNT(id)'];
                        ?>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mcontentbottom"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <div id="fserver">
                        <?php
                        $q = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE `fname`, `fid` FROM `s_set`"));
                        echo "<a href=\"sinfo/".$q['fid'].".html\"><b>".$q['fname']."</b></a>";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div id="rback">
                        <div id="box5t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Gaming Forums</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Counter-Strike</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MuOnline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ragnarok Online</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">World Of Warcraft</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">OnlineGames</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">OnlineTop100</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div class="mback">
                        <div id="box6t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Your ip is: <?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?></li>
                            <li>Servers indexed: <?=$broiserveri?></li>
                            <li>Threads on forum: <?=$broitemi?></li>
                            <li>Posts on forum: <?=$broipostove?></li>
                            <li>Online users: <?=$online?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                    <div class="btop"></div>
                    <div class="mback">
                        <div id="box7t"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://dev-bg.eu" target="_blank">Tutorials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Links Direcotory</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">You link here?</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bbottom"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <div id="fooleft"></div>
                    <div id="foo">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net">Home</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/servers">ViewServers</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/forum/register/">Register</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/crests">Crests</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/forum">Forum</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/add">AddServer</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/contact">Contact</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/terms">Privacy Policy</a> | </li>
                            <li><a href="http://l2topsites.net/terms">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span id="tend">All right reserved L2Topsites © 2010-2011
                        L2Topsites.net is not responsable for any external content.
                    </div>
                    <div id="fooright"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="mainbottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/min/f=javascript.js"></script>
        <!-- NACHALO NA TYXO.BG BROYACH -->
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            d=document;d.write('<a href="http://www.tyxo.bg/?87885" title="Tyxo.bg counter" target=" blank"><img width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="Tyxo.bg counter"');d.write(' src="http://cnt.tyxo.bg/87885?rnd='+Math.round(Math.random()*2147483647));d.write('&sp='+screen.width+'x'+screen.height+'&r='+escape(d.referrer)+'" /><\/a>');//-->
        </script>
        <noscript><a href="http://www.tyxo.bg/?87885" title="Tyxo.bg counter" target="_blank"><img src="http://cnt.tyxo.bg/87885" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="Tyxo.bg counter" /></a></noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error is

```
`Warning: ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Notice: ob_start(): failed to create buffer in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2`
```

I don't know if it is because of that but links are broken too.
Its like when I click somewhere it goes to

```
index.php/page
```

but its should go on

```
index.php?p=page
```

Comment: `You cannot use both ob_gzhandler() and zlib.output_compression. Also note that using zlib.output_compression is preferred over ob_gzhandler().` Straight from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php).

Comment: `Gzip` and `Zlib` both can not work together

Comment: Ok, can i ask how can i disable it? from php.ini? Here is my php.ini http://pastebin.com/8uyPpCcs

Comment: I still didn't get answer :(